# Not sending test folder to production in node express app

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, mean

I am building a node express app, We ship package.json to production but that includes code for unit testing as well. So should i make two package.json one for production and one for development? How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You will have two sections in package.json.

1. dependencies, which will be loaded in develop and production as well.
2. devDependencies, which will be loaded only in development environment but not in Production environment.

All the development dependency modules should be loaded using "save-dev" option. For example the below command will install "Mocha" module only in development environment.

```
 "npm install --save-dev mocha"
```